# Faster replacing in list with a lot of matches

Tags: python, list

just a small problem with list and replacing some list entries.

Maybe some informations around my problem. My idea is really simple and easy. I use the module `mmap` to read out bigger files. It's some FORTRAN-files which have 7 columns and one million lines. Some values didn't fulfill the format of the FORTRAN-output and I just have ten stars. I can't change the format of the output inside the source code and I have to deal with this problem. After loading the file with `mmap` I use `str.split()` to convert the data to a list and then I search for the bad values. Look at the following source code:

```
f = open(fname,'r+b')
A = str(mmap.mmap(f.fileno(),0)[:]).split()
for i in range(A.count('********')):
    A[A.index('********')] = '0.0'
```

I know it's probably not the best solution but it's quick and dirty. Ok. It's quick if `A.count('********')` is small. Actually this is my problem. For some files the replacing method doesn't work really fast. If it's to big it take a lot of time. Is there any other method or a total other way to replace my bad values and don't waste a lot of time?

Thanks for any help or any suggestions.

**EDIT:**

How does the method `list.count()` works? I can also run through whole list and replacing it by my own.

```
for k in range(len(A)):
    if A[k] == '**********': A[k] = '0.0'
```

This would be faster for many replacements. But would it be faster if I only would have one match?

Comment: I know. I already did it. But for the future I only want to run one script and maybe share it with others who will try it on Windows.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Replace `'********'` with `'0.0'`?

Comment: I wanna convert this later to an array. I didn't find a better way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem in your code is the use of "A.index" inside the loop -. The `index` method will walk linearly through your list, from the start up to the next ocurrence of "****" - this turns a O(n) problem into O(n²) - hence your perceived lack of performance.

While using Python the most obvious way is usually the best way to do it: so walking through your list in a Python `for`loop in this case will undoubtley be better than O(n²) loops in C with the cound and index methods. The not so obvious part is the recomended usage of the built-in function "enumerate" to get both an item value and its index from the list on the for loop.

```
f = open(fname,'r+b')
A = str(mmap.mmap(f.fileno(),0)[:]).split()
for i, value in enumerate(A):
    if value == "********":
       A[i] = "0.0"
```

Comment: PS. Since most of the other answers here will avoid the O(n²) problem in your snippet, probably all of them will work for you. I just offered one which resembles your original code.

Comment: It's a nice and theoretical explanation. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you are eventually going to convert this to an array, you might consider using numpy and the `np.genfromtxt` which has the ability to deal with missing data:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html

With a binary file, you can use `np.memmap` and then use masked arrays to deal with the missing elements.

Comment: I will try it. Looks really nice.

Answer (score 0):

If  after converting `A` to one huge string representation, you first could change all the bad values with a single call to the `A.replace('********', '0.0')` method and then split it, you'd have the same result, likely a lot faster. Something like:

```
f = open(fname,'r+b')
A = str(mmap.mmap(f.fileno(),0)[:]).replace('********', '0.0').split()
```

It would use a lot of memory, but that's often the trade-off for speed.

Answer (score 0):

```
fin = open(fname, 'r')
fout = open(fname + '_fixed', 'w')
for line in fin:
    # replace 10 asterisks by 7 spaces + '0.0'
    # If you don't mind losing the fixed-column-width format, 
    # omit the seven spaces
    line = line.replace('**********', '       0.0')
    fout.write(line)
fin.close()
fout.close()
```

Alternatively if your file is smallish, replace the loop by this:

```
fout.write(fin.read().replace('**********', '       0.0'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of manipulating A, try using a list comprehension to make a new A:

```
A = [v if v != '********' else 0.0 for v in A]
```

I think you'll find this surprisingly fast.